# Does FAA 8500-7 expire?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

Does FAA Form 8500-7, a report from an optometrist on a patient's vision, expire? How long after the visit to an optometrist can the vision portion of an aviation medical examination be skipped?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it expires. It would be a staggeringly stupid loophole if one could avoid vision testing for their whole career just by visiting an optometrist once.

I can't find a specific answer for how long it's good for, but the FAA considers medical records to be current if they are no more than 90 days old. I don't see why this would be any different.

On the other hand, your AME may feel differently. If you need to know, you should ask your AME before your medical appointment whether they will accept your 8500-7 in lieu of a vision test.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a specific expiration time. In my opinion the validity of the 8500-7 would be based on the reason it was required in the first place, and the AME's determination that the information/data on the form was still relevant and adequately reflected the current status of you vision health and, therefore, an additional exam at the AME's office was unnecessary.